# Saving user's input into a HashMap and writing into a file

Tags: java, file, hashmap

My program supposed to take orders(maps) from users and saves it into Map inside of the Map and writes into a file. When user input several orders(Maps) only the last one is written into a file not all of them.
I don't understand why that's happening. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thank you

```
    private Map<LocalDate, Map<Integer, OrderDTO>> orders = new HashMap<>();
//user creates orders
public OrderDTO addOrder(OrderDTO order)  { 
    Map<Integer, OrderDTO> currentOrder = new HashMap<>();
    LocalDate ld = order.getLd();
    order.setOrderN(counter++);
    currentOrder.put(order.getOrderN(), order);      
    orders.put(ld, currentOrder); 
    return order;
}

//user selects "save current work"
    public void saveWork(LocalDate ld) { 
        writeOrder(ld);
    }

//writing into a file
   private void writeOrder(LocalDate ld) { 
        String date = ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMddyyyy"));
        String fileName = ORDER_FILE + date + ".txt";
        PrintWriter out;
            out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        Map<Integer, OrderDTO> myOrders = orders.get(ld);
        if (myOrders == null) {
            return;
        }
        List<OrderDTO> ordersList = new ArrayList<>(myOrders.values());
        for (OrderDTO order : ordersList) {
            out.println(order.getOrderN() + DELIMITER
                    + order.getCustomer() + DELIMITER
                    + order.getState() + DELIMITER
                    + order.getProduct() + DELIMITER
.........
            out.flush();
        }
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: When you declare FileWriter , it’s second argument is append which allow you to add lines to existing file not overwriting it. Try, it may help

Comment: out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));

Comment: @VladimirLabliuk, thank you! Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. :-((( 
only the last order is saved into the file

Comment: Also, I’m not sure but out.flush is unnecessary method as PrintWriter provide auto flush, and it may block your loop